# Грамотное API, underscoreCase, camelCase

Tags: java, json, vue.js, rest, spring-boot

В vuejs мы создали объект для отправки, json, давая имена через camelCase

Но в моделях java мы даем имена полям underscoreCase (потому что имена колонок принято через _)

Автоматом @RequestBody ищет имена underscoreCase , а c vuejs мы шлем camelCase

Как **правильно** это устаканить?

Может быть в моделях отдельно давать имена для колонок?

Comment: в java хорошим тоном тоже считается camelCase)

Comment: то есть в моделе будет следующее?
    @Column(updatable = false, name = "desire_date_of_completion")
    private Date desireDateOfCompletion;

Comment: да, так и будет выглядеть